# changes/modifications not effected on odoo UI

Tags: odoo

I am trying to update the app list and app module in odoo 11, that I recently modified, but changes not effecting to UI even after I restart the server with "systemctl or service".

Here I am modifying custom reports of sale.order.

`settings - activate the developer mode - technical - reporting - quotation / order`

Relative **sale.report_saleorder** this xml file modifying.

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <report 
            id="action_report_saleorder"
            string="Quotation / Orderr"
            model="sale.order" 
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            file="sale.report_saleorder" 
            name="sale.report_saleorder"
            print_report_name="(object.state in ('draft', 'sent') and 'Quotation - %s' % (object.name)) or 'Order - %s' % (object.name)"
        />
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change anything that is related to database you must have to upgrade app as well.